# How can I prevent my Windows laptop from jumping between two different access points (same SSID) when the signal is similar?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, ssid

We have four Asus routers around our property - one that does the routing, and three others set to access point mode, connected via ethernet.  All on the same pair of SSIDs - "My house 2.4GHz" & "My house 5GHz".

Often, only one router is within range, and when I move across the property with my laptop it switches to a different router quite seemlessly.

But there's one room which gets good signal from two different routers.  In general use I don't notice it switching, but my PuTTy connections die constantly.

I'm using Windows 10 pro.  It's a Dell XPS 7590 laptop.  Is there anything I can do to change the sensitivity so that it only switches networks when it really has to, not when it thinks one might be marginally better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the wifi card in your laptop to prefer a 5ghz band over 2.4 ghz and vise versa. Go to Network and Internet in control panel, from the left pane, click on change adapter settings. Right click on your wifi adapter and click properties. Then click on configure. Click on the advanced tab in the next box and you should be able to select the preferred Signal band and set it to what you want it to prefer.

Alternatively, you could change the SSID of your 2.4 or 5 ghz networks to different names. Then connect to one at a time.